# Xamarin - Android.GoogleMap remove marker

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-api-3

I am using the `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap` package in Xamarin forms, and I can't seem to find a function to remove an instance of a `Marker`. I have saved a reference to all of my `Marker` in a `List<Marker>` and need to delete them periodically to replace them with new `Marker`

Here is my code:

```
var markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.Draggable(false);
markerOptions.SetTitle(userLocations[i].user_id);
markerOptions.SetPosition(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.longitude)));
markerOptions.SetSnippet("Latitude: " + Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.latitude) + " Longitude: " + Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.longitude));
markerOptionsList.Add(markerOptions); //List<Marker>
map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map.AddMarker() returns a `Marker` object. You must store this in a list to reference when you want to remove a `Marker`. The remove function is just `marker.Remove();`

Create list of markers:

```
List<Marker> marketList = new List<Marker>;
```

Add markers:

```
var markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.Draggable(false);
markerOptions.SetTitle(userLocations[i].user_id);
markerOptions.SetPosition(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.longitude)));
markerOptions.SetSnippet("Latitude: " + Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.latitude) + " Longitude: " + Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.longitude));
Marker M = map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
markerList.Add(M);
```

To remove markers:

```
 foreach (Marker m in markerList)
 {
     m.Remove();
 }
```